# How to select the whole cell content in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> inside a cell it does nothing. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your cell » press <kbd>F2</kbd> » Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Home</kbd>